# ForEach acting up

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a storage system in a thing I am doing, and I have run into a curious problem:

Here is part of my `StorageGroup` class, its purpose is to handle values in transit between database and memory

```
public final class StorageGroup<T> {

@Getter private Map<String, StorageValue> data;
@Getter private String key;

public StorageGroup(String key) {
    this(key, new HashMap<>());
}

private StorageGroup(String key, Map<String, StorageValue> data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.key = key;
}...
```

The important thing here is the `@Getter private Map<String, StorageValue> data;`, the `@Getter` annotation is from Lombok, I use it to generate getters and setters without the mess. The problem is that when I try to use `STORAGEGROUPINSTANCE.getData().forEach()`, it does this:

[image]

I have to cast the two Objects in the BiConsumer to String and StorageGroup respectively, and when I try to do this:
[image]

I just get an error. What gives?

I'm not quite sure how this is a raw type problem, because I explicitly defined the types here: `@Getter private Map<String, StorageValue> data;`

Comment: In Lambda, are you supposed to have a `type` with the variables? Isn't it just `(k) -> {}`?

Comment: You can do either, for example `(Object a, Object b) -> {}` or simply `(a, b) -> {}`, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Hint:  `writeGroup(StorageGroup group)` is a raw type.